# How to change the style of the popup preview blob using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to change the styling of the popup window this opens, but can't figure out how to make it work at all..

```js
function preview() {
  temp = document.editorial.textarea3.value;
  preWindow = open("", "preWindow", "status=no,toolbar=n,menubar=y");
  preWindow.document.style = 'background-color: #222';
  preWindow.document.open();
  preWindow.document.write(temp);
  preWindow.document.close();
}
```

In this script, I only used `background-color` since it's easier to see if it took effect, but what I really need is to specify its width, height, and position.

I can't find anything how to do this, or maybe because I'm not sure what's it really called..

Anyways, thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Styling is not applied to documents, but to elements contained within a document.

Answer (score 1):

Document.write the style. It is not the document element you can style, but the content

```
function preview() {
  temp = document.editorial.textarea3.value;
  preWindow = open("", "preWindow", "menubar,width=500,height=500");
  preWindow.document.write(`<body style="background-color: #222">${temp}</body>`);
  preWindow.document.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for responding and this is really good solution, however it seems to only style the content itself, but I'd also like to change the width and height of the popup window itself.. Can you pls show me how to do it?

Comment: See update. You style the window on the open

Comment: Oh, this is perfect. Thank you very much, this solves it!

Answer (score 1):

You can style the body tag after the `write`

And to change the size you can use `windowFeatures` params of [open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Like:

```js
function preview() {
  temp = document.editorial.textarea3.value;
  preWindow = open("", "preWindow", "status=no,toolbar=n,menubar=y,width=100,height=100");
  preWindow.document.open();
  preWindow.document.write(temp);
  preWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#222';
  preWindow.document.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. Can you pls show me how I can change the size of the document itself? I'd like it to be a smaller window...